# What is TestSuite?

Tags: java, junit, test-suite

I am relatively new to Java and new to JUnit testing.
It's absolutely clear to me what the `Test` class uis, but the `TestSuite` class confuses me.
Can someone explain me  what `TestSuite` is for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its a collection of tests.  It allows you to run such a collection as a group.

Example from the first link I found with google.

```
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class EcommerceTestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {

        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        //
        // The ShoppingCartTest we created above.
        //
        suite.addTestSuite(ShoppingCartTest.class);

        //
        // Another example test suite of tests.
        // 
        suite.addTest(CreditCardTestSuite.suite());

        //
        // Add more tests here
        //

        return suite;
    }

    /**
     * Runs the test suite using the textual runner.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a group of tests that you (or someone) define once which you can run with the click of a button. The tests are automatically run and "marked", and if any test fails you are informed of details.

Answer (score 1):

there are some good definitions here: http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class.html